# php cannot find Class when using namespace

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a object of a class from another file. Both file is located in the same folder & I used 'namespace App' in the both files. In the login files I'm trying to get the class object but it couldn't find the class. Codes are given below.

Database Class : 'Database.php'

```
<?php
    namespace App;

    require_once 'config.php'; 

class Database{

    private $db;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->db =  new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    }

    public function getConnection(){

        return $this->db;

    }
```

login.php file :

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use App\Database; 

    require_once 'config.php'; 


    $DB = new Database(); 

    $con = $DB->getConnection;
```

When I execute login.php , it says Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Database' not found in login.php on line 10

Comment: `use Database;` if you're in the same `\App` namespace as the class you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missing to require database file. Also, call the method by the following way. You are calling a property getConnection that is not available.

```
<?php
namespace App;
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'Database.php';

use App\Database;

$DB = new Database();
$con = $DB->getConnection();
```

Comment: So, I've to require the files always event though I use namespace?

Comment: Yeah @MisbahAhmad

Comment: Is there any way to avoid require?

Comment: @MisbahAhmad ***YES***: Use a [PHP Autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: If you don't want to use require each time then use php's spl_autoload_register() function to automatically call classes @MisbahAhmad

Comment: If you install composer, you can include vendor/autoload.php in you mvc application index.php

Answer (score 2):

- If you are in the root namespace:

`use \App\Database;` You want to tell PHP to search for `App` namespace in the namespace root, if that's where it is.

- If you are in the `App` namespace:

`use Database;` You want to tell PHP to search for `Database` in the *current namespace*, if that's where it is.

- If you are in *another* namespace:

If you're in another namespace (such as `\Blob`) then reference from the root, `\App\Database`, as above.

---

> ```
> namespace App;
>
> use App\Database;
> ```

This is currently looking for \App\App\Database and so is telling you that `App\Database` is not found in the `\App` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing the namespace in:

```
namespace App;
```

You do not need to then include the namespace in the 'use'.

```
namespace App;
use Database;
```